# Book where people get implanted microchips and a segment of the population is eliminated

Tags: story-identification, books

I recall a book years ago about a tech expansion which culminated in humans with microchips in their necks. All money became electronic and a tech company can/does eliminate a whole cohort of the population with undesirable traits.

But one computer programmer/survivalist is syphoning off money from a bank with rounding to X decimal places.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when was "years ago?"  How were the people "eliminated?"  Was it a function of the chips?

Comment: Sounds like a mashup of Doctor Who's [_The Long Game_ (S01E07)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Game) and _Office Space_.